# Unexpected pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed exception

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

I randomly get the following errors (i.e most of the times the scripts work fine)

```
File ".../backend/case_status_consumer.py", line 28, in <module>
    channel.start_consuming()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 955, in start_consuming
    self.connection.process_data_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 240, in process_data_events
    if self._handle_read():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 348, in _handle_read
    super(BlockingConnection, self)._handle_read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 351, in _handle_read
    self._on_data_available(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1285, in _on_data_available
    self._process_frame(frame_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1365, in _process_frame
    self._deliver_frame_to_channel(frame_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 976, in _deliver_frame_to_channel
    return self._channels[value.channel_number]._handle_content_frame(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/channel.py", line 792, in _handle_content_frame
    self._on_deliver(*response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/channel.py", line 886, in _on_deliver
    body)
  File ".../backend/case_status_consumer.py", line 14, in consume_case_status
    case_num['case_year'])
  File ".../backend/src/fetcher/case_update.py", line 132, in case_update
    properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 572, in basic_publish
    (properties, body), False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1159, in _send_method
    self.connection.send_method(self.channel_number, method_frame, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 274, in send_method
    self._send_method(channel_number, method_frame, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1503, in _send_method
    self._send_frame(frame.Method(channel_number, method_frame))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 417, in _send_frame
    super(BlockingConnection, self)._send_frame(frame_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1490, in _send_frame
    self._flush_outbound()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 377, in _flush_outbound
    if self._handle_write():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 365, in _handle_write
    return self._handle_error(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 302, in _handle_error
    self._handle_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 248, in _handle_disconnect
    self._adapter_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 318, in _adapter_disconnect
    self._check_state_on_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 371, in _check_state_on_disconnect
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

And I get a similar error while producing too.

```
File ".../backend/check_for_orders.py", line 115, in <module>
    dated=order_dated, ors_fetch=False)
  File ".../backend/src/fetcher/case_update.py", line 132, in case_update
    properties=pika.BasicProperties(delivery_mode=2))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 572, in basic_publish
    (properties, body), False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 1159, in _send_method
    self.connection.send_method(self.channel_number, method_frame, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 274, in send_method
    self._send_method(channel_number, method_frame, content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1503, in _send_method
    self._send_frame(frame.Method(channel_number, method_frame))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 417, in _send_frame
    super(BlockingConnection, self)._send_frame(frame_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/connection.py", line 1490, in _send_frame
    self._flush_outbound()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 377, in _flush_outbound
    if self._handle_write():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 365, in _handle_write
    return self._handle_error(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 302, in _handle_error
    self._handle_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/base_connection.py", line 248, in _handle_disconnect
    self._adapter_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 318, in _adapter_disconnect
    self._check_state_on_disconnect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pika/adapters/blocking_connection.py", line 371, in _check_state_on_disconnect
    raise exceptions.ConnectionClosed()
pika.exceptions.ConnectionClosed
```

My connection is set to:

```
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost', heartbeat_interval=0))
```

I have even tried setting the heartbeat interval to a longer time (like 60 and 90), but I still get these errors.

I cannot post the full code but what my scripts are doing is, using 'requests' to fetch a page (with timeout as 50 seconds and maximum 4 retries)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is fixed in pika 0.10.0